# Firestore: add or remove elements to existing array with Flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

Is it possible to add or delete elements to an existing array stored in a Firestore document instead of fetching the array, add the element locally and send it back to the store?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Hopefully, yes.

You can append or remove an element using the method update() in combination with `FieldValue.arrayUnion([element])` or `FieldValue.arrayRemove([element])`.

Example:

```
Future<void> appendToArray(String id, dynamic element) async {
  _firestore.collection(RootKey).doc(id).update({
    'myArrayField': FieldValue.arrayUnion([element]),
  });
}

Future<void> removeFromArray(String id, dynamic element) async {
  _firestore.collection(RootKey).doc(id).update({
    'myArrayField': FieldValue.arrayRemove([element]),
  });
}
```

Comment: Thnak you, Your answer is so useful.